# "undefined error" in jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

please some one help to clear this error

I want to show a modal pop(with inside details from database) upon each click of the dynamic boxes without page refresh.I used jquery ajax,but i cant get the values from database.it shows undefined error on the field inside pop up.please see the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("div[id*='window']").live('click', function (e) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'Default2.aspx/get_details',
                  type: 'Get',
                  // dataType: 'json',
                  data: { id: $(this).attr('id').replace(/window/g, '') },
                  success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                      $('<div></div>').appendTo('body').html('<div>' + data.comp_name + '</div><div>' + data.comp_status + '</div>').dialog({
                          modal: true, title: 'owner details', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                          width: 400, height: 200, modal: false, resizable: false, closeOnEscape: false,
                          show: "slide", hide: "explode",

                          close: function (event, ui) {
                              $(this).remove();
                          }
                      });
                  }
              });
          });
      });


  </script>
```

c# code:

```
public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }


  public Company get_details(int id)
  {

      DataSet dset = new DataSet();
      SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KUR;Initial Catalog=Drea;User ID=sa;Password=Sage");
      string qry = "Select comp_companyId,comp_name,comp_status from Company where comp_companyId=" +id+" ";
      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, cn);
      sda.Fill(dset);

      Company entity = new Company();

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, cn);

      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      if (reader.Read())
      {
          entity.Id = int.Parse(reader["comp_companyId"].ToString());
          entity.Name = reader["comp_name"].ToString();
          entity.Status = reader["comp_status"].ToString();
      }

      return entity;
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on the error? Where does it occur, on what line? Also, can you post the response from the server?

Comment: does the alert(data) say undefined? You should be using a datatype in your ajax request if you are expecting a response from the server.

Comment: no inside the pop up instead of field values i got undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Name { get; set; } -> data.Name ...
if u use data.name it will show as undefined. because it is case sensitive
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Scripts/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div[id*='window']").live('click', function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/GetCompanyDetails", type: "Post", dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ id: $(this).attr('id').replace(/window/g, '') }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(eval("(" + msg.d + ")")));

                        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body').html('<div>' + data.Name + '</div><div>' + data.City + '</div>').dialog({
                            modal: true, title: 'Test message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                            width: 460, height: 300, modal: true, resizable: false, closeOnEscape: false,
                            show: "slide", hide: "explode",
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            },
                            close: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="window1">
        Test1
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="window2">
        Test2
    </div>
</body>
</html>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Entity;

namespace CompanyDisplay
{
    public partial class CompayJqueryUI : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public Company GetCompanyDetails(int id)
        {
            if (true)   //authorize 
            {
                //SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KURIOS_WS4;Initial Catalog=Dreams;User ID=sa;Password=SageCRMv71");
                //string qry = "Select comp_companyId,comp_name,comp_status from Company where comp_companyId=@comp_companyId ";
                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, cn);
                //SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                Company entity = new Company();
                entity.Id = 2;
                entity.Name = "Test";
                entity.City = "Bangalore";

                //Or

                //if (reader.Read())
                //{
                //    entity.Id = int.Parse(reader["comp_companyId"].ToString());
                //    entity.Name = reader["comp_name"].ToString();
                //    entity.City = reader["comp_status"].ToString();
                //}

                return entity;
            }
            else
            {
                return new Company();
            }
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using CompanyDisplay;

namespace CompanyDisplay
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetCompanyDetails(int id)
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new CompayJqueryUI().GetCompanyDetails(id));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi in the above code if i keep breakpoint it is not firing to the get details method,so i cant get the database values.I will try this code

Comment: send u r or friend email id . i will send u the zip file.

Comment: namespace shoulde be same for .aspx and .asmx file name and method name should match as WebService.asmx/GetCompanyDetails  in jquery

Comment: k.. i sended u the attachment u can delete the email id.

Comment: public string Name { get; set; } -> data.Name . if u use  data.name it will show as undefined. because it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that I see to check out:

1. Mark your server-side method with the [`[WebMethod]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
2. The actual data is returned in `data.d`, not `data`.